# JIRA dev-status api not returning all files commited

Tags: bitbucket, jira, jira-rest-api

Iam trying to get all the files committed against a JIRA issue. Iam using the following method to get the information

GET /rest/dev-status/1.0/issue/detail?issueId=&applicationType=bitbucket&dataType=pullrequest

The JSON returns all the commits but not full list of files committed. if i commit more than 5 files on a single commit, then only the first 5 files are listed in the JSON. anyways to get the full list of files?

Answer (score 2):

The resource you are using is not part of the public rest API of Jira, so you there is no guarantees around the response you will receive from it. It is very much use at your own risk.

The current implementation limits itself to only fetching the first 5 files changed, if you require more that this you will need to do a call to Bitbucket etc and lookup the diffstat information yourself eg https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/diffstat/%7Bspec%7D